# Problems with reacting to joystick button press

Tags: debounce, joystick

I am trying to use a joystick in a project for device control. Pressing a joystick button should cause incrementing a variable. INPUT_PULLUP mode is used for internal button.

As I understand it, when the button is not pressed there is a HIGH level on the GPIO pin, and there is a LOW level when the button is pressed. The signal read from the button in thd sketch is inverted to HIGH when the circuit is closed.

I used some sketches for eliminating debounce, but in all cases when the button is pressed a stream of incoherent symbols occurs on the serial port. It happens both in the simulator and the IDE.

What can cause this stream on the output when waiting for the message that button is pressed? The symbols also occured when I put a count-variable on the serial port. Does the button debounce look correct?

```cpp
int Joystick_Y = A0;
int Joystick_X = A1;
int Joystick_but = 1;
int X;
int Y;
int X_prev = 0;
int Y_prev = 0;
int butt_flag = 0;
int butt;

const unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;
unsigned long last_press;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Joystick_but, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  butt = !digitalRead(Joystick_but);

  if (butt == 1 && butt_flag == 0 && millis() - last_press > debounceDelay) {
    butt_flag = 1;
    last_press = millis();
    Serial.println("Button was pressed!");
  }

  if (butt == 0 && butt_flag == 1) {
    butt_flag = 0;
  }

  Y = analogRead(Joystick_Y);
  X = analogRead(Joystick_X);
  
  if (X < 512 && X > 485) {
    X = 512;
  }
  if (Y < 512 && Y > 485) {
    Y = 512;
  }

  if ((Y != Y_prev || X != X_prev) && (X != Y)) {
    Serial.print("X: ");
    Serial.print(X);
    Serial.print(" Y: ");
    Serial.println(Y);
  }

  Y_prev = Y;
  X_prev = X;
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: What Arduino are you using exactly? On Uno/Nano pins 0 and 1 are used for the Serial interface. And the debouncedelay of 50ms won't work, when you delay for 500ms at the end of `loop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in @chrisl 's comment: pin 1 on an Arduino Uno/Nano is the TX (transmit) pin for the Serial port. See [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/). This is the pin that is used to transmit serial data to the host.

When the same pin is also used as the joystick button, pressing it will interfere with serial output, causing the incoherent symbols you see to be transmitted.

Solution: Use a different (unused) pin.

Another potential problem is the `delay (500)` at the end of your `loop()` which, as @chrisl also noted, interferes with your debounce and will cause your code to react to button presses and joystick movements very slowly.